# Max Value of the Sum of Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using one table in SQL Server.

This is how the table is displayed originally:

| ItemNo | StoreNo | DemandYr1 | DemandYr2 | DemandYr3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | BB | 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | BB | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 5 | CC | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 3 | AA | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | BB | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | CC | 2 | 2 | 2 |

After using this query,

```
select itemno, storeno, sum(DemandYr1 + DemandYr2 + DemandYr3) as SumDemand
from ExTable 
group by itemno, storeno
order by itemno asc
```

I have gotten the table to this:

| ItemNo | StoreNo | SumDemand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | 5 |
| 1 | BB | 8 |
| 5 | BB | 15 |
| 5 | CC | 6 |
| 3 | AA | 7 |
| 3 | BB | 4 |
| 3 | CC | 6 |

Now, my desired result is to only show the storeno with the highest SumDemand for each ItemNo in a table like this:

| ItemNo | StoreNo | SumDemand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BB | 8 |
| 5 | BB | 6 |
| 3 | CC | 6 |

Since the SumDemand column is not part of the original table and was added by me, I am not sure how to query it to only show the greatest SumDemand for each ItemNo. I understand that if two StoreNo's have the same SumDemand there will be duplicates, that is fine.

** If possible, I would also like to omit any results that = 0. Ex: If an Item No has 0 SumDemand at all stores, I would like to delete. (If this is not possible that is also fine) **

Comment: Your sample query cannot be correct with un-delimited column names containing spaces.

Comment: They don't actually contain spaces, I only typed it that way for clarity in my question.  I have fixed. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a row_number to your select in combination with a CTE.

But you should avoid adding spaces in your column names as the must all be escaped

```
WITH CTE as (
select [item no], [store no], sum([Demand Yr1] + [Demand Yr2] + [Demand Yr3]) as SumDemand
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Item No] ORDER BY  sum([Demand Yr1] + [Demand Yr2] + [Demand Yr3]) DESC ) rn
from ExTable 
group by [item no], [store no])
  SELECT [item no], [store no],SumDemand
  FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
order by [item no] asc
```

| item no | store no | SumDemand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BB | 8 |
| 3 | AA | 7 |
| 5 | BB | 15 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jSO99JIk)